# How to query a cumulative sum up to a specific value in SQL

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have a SQL table which looks like this:

```
Id  Quantity
1   24.857    
2   24.84
3   24.881
4   24.823
```

I need to select a cumulative sum of the quantity until a specified value is reached - let's say 50.
So with the above table, I would need the query to return the first 3 rows. (The sum of the quantity in the first two rows does not reach 50, so I need the third row as well).

Now I have the below code which is close but not quite right. The result of this query returns only the first two rows of the table which isn't sufficient.

```
DECLARE @point INT = 50;

WITH x(Id, Quantity, RowNum, TotalQuantity) AS
(
  SELECT
    id, quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM inventory
)

SELECT x.Id, x.RowNum, x.Quantity, x.TotalQuantity
FROM x
WHERE x.TotalQuantity <= @point
ORDER BY x.Id
```

This query results in the following:

```
Id  RowNum  Quantity   TotalQuantity
1   1       24.857     24.857
2   2       24.84      49.697
```

I feel as though I need a `WHILE` loop in here somewhere which I have tried to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more cte to get the first row when the total quantity is >= @point. Then join with the existing cte.

```
WITH x(Id, Quantity, RowNum, TotalQuantity) AS
(
  SELECT
    id, quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM inventory
)
, y as (select min(rownum) as minrownum from x where totalquantity >= @point)
SELECT x.Id, x.RowNum, x.Quantity, x.TotalQuantity
FROM x
JOIN y on x.rownum <= y.minrownum
ORDER BY x.Id
```

Comment: Lovely. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LAG to look at the prior row.

```
WITH x(Id, Quantity, RowNum, TotalQuantity, TotalQuantityPrior) AS
(
  SELECT
    id, quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS TotalQuantity,
    LAG(TotalQuantity,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS TotalQuantityPrior
  FROM inventory
)

SELECT x.Id, x.RowNum, x.Quantity, x.TotalQuantity
FROM x
WHERE x.TotalQuantityPrior <= @point
ORDER BY x.Id
```

I use 0 as default -- you might want -1 if you can have 0 as @point or maybe something else depending on your business rules.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx